# Storing xml content in a java string variable and writing to a text area in selenium

Tags: java, xml

My task is to store config file content of xml format in an java string and write to the textarea on the UI . I have used a string variable which is able to store only 256 chars so it is unable to store the total content.

Comment: Your task is to **read the java tag** and use the correct site.

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it stands your question would also be closed on [SO].